# Harry Potter blood purity question?

Tags: harry-potter

So I've been re-reading the HP novels as of late and the topic of blood purity intrigued me after I supplemented the novels with info on the matter. I first became interested in this after reading that Harry and Ginny's children are considered to be "half-blood." As far as I have gathered from the books and Rowling's statement on the matter, blood purity is usually traced back 2 generations to the grandparents. I would assume this is more or less the general wizarding consensus excluding various extremists like the Blacks, Malfoys, and Gaunts. I've read that no family's blood is completely pure by the time of the novel, even if they pretend it is and it's been revealed by several characters that fanatics will just ignore any muggle relations within their family. It seems an awful lot to me like the One Drop Rule... That even if you had a great-grandparent that was black, you in turn would technically be considered black as well. My question is, could a half-blood eventually "purify" their blood again by marrying a pure-blood and their descendants doing the same? For example, if Harry's daughter, Lily married Malfoy's son, Scorpius would their children then be pureblood by common belief? Or would Harry's being half-blood also mean his grand kids would be the same? What if their children in turn married another pureblood? Technically since Harry's mother was a muggle-born witch and his father was pureblood and Ginny was also pureblood, their children would have 3/4 blood purity. So one would think the line would resume "full" purity if Harry's child married a pureblood. *Note: I'm not talking about the perspective of Voldemort and his followers, who would argue Ginny's status as a blood traitor and would claim that any traceable muggle-born lineage would taint the blood.

Comment: From the linked answer: "In Germany itself, the Ahnenpass and Nuremberg Laws classified people as Jews if they descended from three or four Jewish grandparents. A person with one or two Jewish grandparents was a Mischling, a crossbreed, of "mixed blood" (Wiki quoting official Nazi rules).

Comment: So, under Nazi laws (which Rowling used as inspiration for Blood Purity ideals), if Harry's child (1/4 blood) married a pureblood, a result (1/8blood) would be technically considered "[Mischling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mischling) of the 3rd degree". They were slightly less mistreated by Nazis **but were still not considered "real" Aryans** (IIRC they were prohibited from being members of Nazi Party or holding posts in government). So, by those sets of rules, translated back to Potter world, you can't "fully purify" by marrying into pureblood family; definitely NOT 3rd generation.